# Squeeze rectangle from one side in illustrator or photoshop

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I want to make a rectangle of squeeze from one side in Photoshop or Illustrator. Just like showing in the picture below. I am trying it in the illustrator by Effect -> Wrap ->  . But there is not any one style that is like my requirement. Is there any way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: In Photoshop, it is is `Filter`->`Liquify` and then the `Warp tool` that looks like a finger at top left of screen. But this is not a programming question and doesn't belong here.

Comment: @MarkSetchell. Your solution is not working properly. It is squeezing but not properly.

Answer (score 1):

In illustrator:

1) Group the objects you want to warp

2) Rotate them 90 degrees

3) Effects >> Warp >> Arc Upper... (Positive value = convex, negative value = concave)

4) Object >> Expand appearance

5) Rotate so it is upright again.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA Code does what you need:

```
Sub draw()
Dim Doc As Object
Dim New_Path As Object

    Set Doc = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application").ActiveDocument
    Set New_Path = Doc.PathItems.Add
    New_Path.SetEntirePath (Array(Array(100, 100), Array(100, 200), Array(120, 200), Array(120, 100)))
    New_Path.Closed = True
    New_Path.PathPoints(3).RightDirection = Array(110, 180)
    New_Path.PathPoints(4).LeftDirection = Array(110, 120)
End Sub
```